# Does EU geoblocking apply to businesses outside EU?

Tags: gdpr, european-union

[This](https://support.stripe.com/questions/eu-geo-blocking-regulation-changes)
: https://support.stripe.com/questions/eu-geo-blocking-regulation-changes
states that EU has passed a law preventing geoblocking .Does this
apply to businesses outside EU. It is favourable to block the whole of the EU because of GDPR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes

The regulation applies to all merchants operating in the EU irrespective of where they are domiciled.

If you don't operate in the EU, then it doesn't apply to you.

Comment: So if no opperations are carried in EU no fear of such laws.

Comment: The goal was to prevent geoblocking **within** the EU. Sample: price in country EU-a was more expensive than in country EU-b. Users in country EU-a were **not** allowed to buy the product in country EU-b (or redirected to country EU-a).